# unable to receive data sent with get request in node server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I am sending a data along with $http.get request like below to node server.

```
$http.get("/deletebookData",{pathsrc : "a"}).success(function (result) {});
```

on node js i am not able to receive the {pathsrc : "a"} sent in get request.

```
app.get("/deletebookData", function (req, response) {
      console.log(req.body);
});
```

only empty json is printed in console

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the data. Check the `$http.get` documentation.

If you want to include params in your request use:

```
$http({
  url: '/deletebookData',
  method: 'GET'
  params: {pathsrc : "a"}
})
.then(function(){..});
```

Or:

```
$http.get('/deletebookData',{params: {pathsrc :'a'}}).then(function(){..});
```

Or build your url manualy:

```
$http.get("/deletebookData?pathsrc=a").then(function(){..})
```

(Also, please note that since angular 1.4 `.success()` is deprecated. Use `.then()` instead)

Comment: The question about how to send data to server in request body